# Using an object as the parameter of an external function in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, dllexport

Let's say I have a timer object in C#:

```
public class Timer {
    private int currentTime;
    private int lastTime;

    public int GetTimePassed() {
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use this object as a parameter in an external function? Like so:

```
public class Program {
    [DllImport("example.dll"), CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl]
    extern void ExampleFunction(Timer arg);
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void ExampleFunction(Timer arg) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-classes-structures-and-unions#structures-sample to get you going. If you need more samples. The keyword to search for is marshalling.

Comment: A sorry wrong localized link. should be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-classes-structures-and-unions#structures-sample